# python-mysqldb : How to efficiently get millions/billions of records from database?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

- I have a table from which I have to fetch around 7 million records, and this will go upto billion records too(since data is added everyday)
- I am using mysql-python to connect to remote MySQL database
- I query like the following

> cursor = conn.cursor()
>   cursor.execute(query)
>   return cursor

and try to print them as

```
sql = 'select * from reading table;' # has 7 million records
cursor = MySQLDB.execute(sql)
for row in cursor:
        print row
```

- It is taking forever to print it

On server, I see the process is running

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 3769 mysql     20   0 1120m 276m 5856 S  125  1.7   2218:09 mysqld
```

**Question**
What is the efficient way of querying a table with {m,b}illions of records using python?

Thank you

Comment: What is your sql query (contents of the `sql` variable)?

Comment: Did you try not printing anything to check if you're not adding another bottleneck?

Comment: When is printing 7 million records all at once ever considered efficient?

Comment: print is pretty damn slow, I really don't think iterating the cursor is what's taking time. by then the result is already back from mysql.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and assume you're not *really* displaying 7 million records in one view. So, why retrieve them all at once? Do it in chunks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest two options:

1. Direct the required data into a file with `SELECT OUTFILE` or even with a mysql console, and work with the file.
2. You should understand that by default, mysql sends the whole resultset to the client, and the client mimicks as if the data is read row by row (though the whole result is already in memory, or failed if there is not enough memory). Alternatively, the resultset can be formed on the server-side. For that you will need to add `cursor=MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor` parameter to MySQLdb.connect (See http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html for details).

Comment: You can also get a `SSCursor` by passing `MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor` to the `cursor()` method of a connection object.